# Handle 1062 Duplicate entry Exception in symfony2

Tags: symfony, exception

I have an PDO Exception:

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0_L525_H132_A000_P624_M600' for key 'UNIQ_88A3CEF5FB7BD549'

So that the script will be continued after an exception will happen?

Actually, my entity looks like:

```
/** @ORM\Table(indexes={@Index(columns={"Soundex"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("Soundex")
 */
class SoundexData
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Soundex", type="string", length=255, nullable=true,unique=true)
     */
    private $soundex;
```

And I try to import data by using:

```
try {
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();
}
catch(\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) 
{
    // handle exception
}
```

To avoid breaking the script and continue after an exception happens, I'm stucking :(

So how can I handle this?

Reason for all that is, that I don't want to have double entries in my DB, so I thought it would be easier to ignore doubles, rather that checking each dataset if it already exist in database (no MySQL request is the fastest request ;))

Comment: Just replace `\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException` with `\PDOException` ?

Comment: No this won't work . When I use \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException, I get an "the entityManager is closed message. When I use PDO... I get the exception like described on top

Comment: When an exception is thrown the entity manager automatically closes itself and basically becomes unusable.  This is by design.  There are just too many things that can go wrong to try and continue.  You basically need to either check first or drop down and use the dbal connection object instead of the ORM entity manager.

Answer (score -1):

You should catch the PDOException instead:

```
try {
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();
} catch(\PDOException $e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Comment: IMO you're not supposed to know that the ORM uses PDO.